# Running Tomcat from Eclipse: how to add a virtual host?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, testing

This is my setup:

- Eclipse Juno
- Maven project
- Maven Tomcat plugin
- Project with debug configuration: "Goals: tomcat:run"

If I debug my application it runs perfectly on

```
http://localhost:8080/app/
```

But I want to add extra data on that server that should be reachable on

```
http://localhost:8080/data/
```

Where can I add that data directory? And do I have to add it in some properties file to act as a virtual host?

I tried adding in these directories, but both without success:

```
/workspace/app/target/tomcat/webapps/data/
/workspace/app/target/tomcat/work/localEngine/localhost/data/
```

Thanks for any help,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app context-root is `/app`, which in Tomcat is the name of your war by default. Tomcat will map the content under your `/src/main/webapp` folder into the `/app` context root of your Tomcat instance. You will need to deploy another module named data.war so it maps to `http://localhost:8080/data`.

Alternatively, if you want it to be the same module, you can set the server root as the context root of your app, editing `server.xml` in Tomcat config:

```
<Context path="" docBase="webapps/app" debug="0" reloadable="true">  
</Context>
```

And then having your folder structure in the app like this:

```
src/main/webapp
->app
-->Content of your original app, mapped to http://localhost:8080/app
->data
-->Content of data, mapped to http://localhost:8080/data
```